# How to bring electric cooker in chimney's coverage when there's gas hob occupying the whole place

Tags: kitchens, chimney, humidity, steam, gas-burner

I have a chimney which covers the 4 burner gas hob but I don't have any space to keep my electric rice cooker.

the electric rice cooker produces lots of steam which increases the humidity level at kitchen.

This makes the near by areas bit sticky or greasy.

I'm looking for some hack to fix the problem.

I can just place a piece of wood on top of the inactive burner but I'm not comfortable with that because it's an eye sore.

Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Is placing it abutting the single burner and pointing the vent hole centrally not enough to direct the water vapor (steam's invisible) up the exhaust? Can you fit it between all 3 burners? You could make an extension to the cooker's vent hole with a steel straw or emptied bic pen tube and some jb-weld or modeling clay to move the egress over the side.

Comment: Use a stone tile, or a nicer piece of wood, or a griddle or whatever suits your sense of **Not An Eye Sore** - which only you know, so this is a poor quality question.

Comment: If you put it close enough to the exhaust, it should suck most of it up.  We regularly put other appliances on the stove for this purpose, just dont turn the stove on.  If you use a chopping board or tile, you dont have to leave it there all the time.

Comment: @dandavis - Thanks your idea of JB-Weld with steel straw sounds interesting to me. I will try that. Thanks

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Griddle seems to be easy enough for me. I have some frying non-stick pan and cast iron pan .. I can probably place the griddle on a non ignited burner and use this electric rice cooker. seems to be easy enough :) Why didn't i think of it before :(

Comment: @RohitGupta - My hob is almost 2 by 2 feet and my chimney is 2.5 feet high from hob and my chimney is 60cm and  has suction capacity 1200 m3/hr having said that it still struggles get the vapor in from the sides of hob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the vent fan.

There's almost always a damper on the exhaust for efficiency purposes, so if the fan is off, the vent hood isn't extracting anything. You fix this by turning on the vent fan, and perhaps turning the speed up.

If you still need more, move the rice cooker closer to the vent hood. If the vent hood is working properly, it should extract over a rather broad area.

Comment: Chimney is 60cm and has suction capacity 1200 m3/hr . Even if I keep near the hob I don't see the steam getting completely sucked by and sometimes wind changes the direction of steam also

Comment: Crack open a nearby window. You'll get much better suction capacity from that direction to take up the water vapor. It's OK to not catch it all, in winter it's usually too dry indoors anyway.